# Regarding the number of iterations functionality

Tags: orange

I have a query regarding the number of iterations functionality in Orange, which is available with several widgets.

For instance, in the neural networks widget, the maximum number of iterations is currently 10000. However, I often come across problems where it takes more than 10000 iterations for a problem to converge.

Is there a way to increase the number of iterations to for instance 1000000?

Comment: Not sure if my query has reached the relevant person, but it would be appreciated if the issue raised could be resolved. I’ve been waiting for several days, but no response yet.